# Nested boosting for a field in solr Search

Tags: solr

Team,

We want to do field level nested boosting. We are trying some query but from documentation it is not clear how the query should be formed.

**fielddemo:(google^2.0 facebook^1.0)^10.0 OR fieldonedemo:(yahoo^2.0 twitter^1.0)^5.0**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add boostquery terms to your query:

```
bq=fielddemo:google^20
bq=fielddemo:facebook^10
bq=fieldonedemo:yahoo^10
bq=fieldonedemo:twitter^5
```